# lim colim,side by side,functor,category

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors, limits-colimits

What is exactly/intuitively meant by putting lim and colim side by side with elements as subscripts
under them, ranging in some category,like here:
$$\mathbb {ind}-C(F,G)≔\mathbb{lim}_{ d∈D} \mathbb{colim}_ {e∈E}C(Fd,Ge)$$.

For $C,F,G,D$ and $E$ see
[here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ind-object).

Comment: recall from freshman calculus that if our function is order preserving then the limit can be found by considering sups and infs, and for posets limits and colimits are just infs and sups, with these in mind what does $\inf_{n \geq 0} \sup_{m ≥ n} x_m$ mean? Perhaps this limit-superior analogue is of help ... I know nothing of these ind-objects...